# How to set Python module like uwsgi in AWS beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, saleor

Some applications I am deploying are using `__init__.py` instead of `wsgi.py` or `application.py` (`app/wsgi/__init__.py`) and setting a WSGI module like **uwsgi** would be great (`module = app.wsgi:application` in uwsgi.in)

```
myapp/wsgi/__init__.py == myapp.wsgi:application
```

**.ebextensions/django.config**:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: saleor/uwsgi/__init__.py (!!! DOES NOT WORK !!!)
```

**uwsgi.ini**:

```
[uwsgi]
die-on-term = true
http-socket = :$(PORT)
log-format = UWSGI uwsgi "%(method) %(uri) %(proto)" %(status) %(size) %(msecs)ms [PID:%(pid):Worker-%(wid)] [RSS:%(rssM)MB]
master = true
max-requests = 100
memory-report = true
module = saleor.wsgi:application
processes = 4
static-map = /static=/app/static
mimefile = /etc/mime.types
```

*New account at AWS forums so can't post a question there yet. SO to the rescue!*

Comment: Why is `wsgi` a directory and not python file? (wsgi/__init__.py vs wsgi.py)

Comment: 3rd-party software has it. I do have control over it but changing the source is not the best solution.

Comment: Please update your question with the error you're getting, include logs off you can. The setting you're using should work fine.

Comment: @patrys it says the WSGIPath is wrong